# GetByteArrayElements uses direct memory?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, out-of-memory, directmemory

I got a Direct Memory OOM in my program.

The program used `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()` in java, and C++ side writes data into that buffer.
But when I tried to change the `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()` to `ByteBuffer.allocate()` and using `GetByteArrayElements()` to write the data. I still got the same Direct Memory OOM.

I'm confused, is that `GetByteArrayElements()` copys the array using direct memory?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK GetByteArrayElements is for accessing a `byte[]` which is what backs a heap ByteBuffer.allocate().

To access a direct ByteBuffer you need to use GetDirectBufferAddress and
GetDirectBufferCapacity

http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/jni-14.html